# Creating custom "equality operator" for PostgreSQL type (point) for DISTINCT calls

Tags: postgresql, types, operator-overloading, distinct

In one of my tables, I have a column that is defined as the PostgreSQL type [`point`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-geometric.html). I use this for the [`earthdistance`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/earthdistance.html) module—specifically, the `<@>` distance operator. (Yes, I know about PostGIS, but it was far more complex than my needs, which is simply given a table with lat/long pairs, order the table by distance with room for error from a provided lat/long.)

However, `point` appears to have no equality implemented, so any `DISTINCT` call on the table like `SELECT DISTINCT * FROM mytable` results in the following error:

```
ERROR: could not identify an equality operator for type point
```

Though it's generally unadvisable to patch built-in types, I don't mind in this case doing so, and I tried to create my own `=` operator for `point`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION compare_points_equality(point1 POINT, point2 POINT)
  RETURNS BOOLEAN AS $$
  SELECT point1[0] = point2[0] AND point1[1] = point1[1];
$$ LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE;

CREATE OPERATOR = (
  LEFTARG = POINT,
  RIGHTARG = POINT,
  PROCEDURE = compare_points_equality,
  COMMUTATOR = =,
  NEGATOR = !=,
  HASHES,
  MERGES
);
```

But even after creating this, I get the same error.  What am I supposed to do to create the "equality operator" if not create `=`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To select distinct values Postgres must have the ability to sort the column.
You need to create a complete btree [operator class](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createopclass.html) for type point, i.e. five operators (`<`, `<=`, `=`, `>=`, `>`) and a function comparing two points and returning integer, as it is described in [the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xindex.html).

For the operator `=` you can use the existing function `point_eq(point, point)`:

```sql
create operator = (
    leftarg = point, 
    rightarg = point, 
    procedure = point_eq, 
    commutator = =);
```

Example definition of operator `<`:

```sql
create function point_lt(point, point)
returns boolean language sql immutable as $$
    select $1[0] < $2[0] or $1[0] = $2[0] and $1[1] < $2[1]
$$;

create operator < (
    leftarg = point, 
    rightarg = point, 
    procedure = point_lt, 
    commutator = >);
```

Define the operators `<=`, `=>` and `>` in a similar way. Having all five operators, create a function:

```sql
create function btpointcmp(point, point)
returns integer language sql immutable as $$
    select case 
        when $1 = $2 then 0
        when $1 < $2 then -1
        else 1
    end
$$;
```

And finally:

```sql
create operator class point_ops
    default for type point using btree as
        operator 1 <,
        operator 2 <=,
        operator 3 =,
        operator 4 >=,
        operator 5 >,
        function 1 btpointcmp(point, point);
```

With the class `point_ops` defined you can select distinct point values and order rows by the column of type point, e.g.:

```sql
with q(p) as (
    values 
        ('(1,1)'::point),
        ('(1,2)'::point),
        ('(2,1)'::point),
        ('(1,1)'::point))
select distinct *
from q
order by 1 desc;

   p   
-------
 (2,1)
 (1,2)
 (1,1)
(3 rows)
```

You can also create (unique) index on a point column.

---

Update.

> Where the function `point_eq(point, point)` comes from? Why does it already exist?

Postgres has over 2800 auxiliary functions that support operators, indexes, standard functions, etc. You can list them by querying [`pg_proc`,](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-proc.html) e.g.:

```sql
select oid::regprocedure as function
from pg_proc
where pronamespace::regnamespace = 'pg_catalog'::regnamespace
and proname like 'point%'
```

The function `point_eq(point, point)` is used in implementation of some [geometric functions and operators.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-geometry.html)

Comment: Sadly I wasn't able to use this answer because I don't have superuser access to the database, and apparently that's required to create an operator class.  Not sure why.

Comment: Yes, as stated in [the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createopclass.html):
*Presently, the creating user must be a superuser. (This restriction is made because an erroneous operator class definition could confuse or even crash the server.)*

Comment: is the > at the end correct create operator < (leftarg = point, rightarg = point, procedure = point_lt, commutator = >); or should it be a <

Comment: @JuanDiego - it's correct. *The commutator operator should be identified if one exists, so that Postgres can reverse the order of the operands if it wishes.* Vide https://momjian.us/main/writings/pgsql/aw_pgsql_book/node217.html

Comment: `For the operator = you can use the existing function point_eq(point, point):` Where come from `point_eq`? Why it is already existing?