# Query using subset of path in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, geometry, postgresql-9.6

Given this table:

```
 id |            points (path)                 |
----+------------------------------------------+
  1 | ((1,2),(3,4),(5,6),(7,8))                |
```

Is it possible to achieve the following using a single geometric operator and a path argument (**sequential** subset of the containing path), like `((3,4),(5,6))`?

`select * from things where points @> '(3,4)' and points @> '(5,6)';`

Comment: Your question is not clear to me, do you want to extract points from an existing path? Do they need to be connected? By the way, here's an [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/2cc5e/2).

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I was hoping to be able to find any `things` whose `points` contained the parameterized sub-path. The query I provided above does do that, but I'd like it to be a singular operation, if possible, since the sub-paths in my application will be considerably longer and I'd like to avoid manually constructing a chain of `points @> '(a,aa)' and ... and points @> '(z,zz)'`s. Also, thanks for creating that SQLFiddle! I wasn't aware of that service.

Comment: @pdoherty926 Your query does not match path inside path, only if the path contains the points. See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/2cc5e/51/0 . Is that your intension?

Comment: @SzymonLukaszczyk The query presented above is meant to convey my best-yet attempt at finding a solution to this problem. I may be conflating terms, but I'd like to use a sub-path (e.g. list of points) to find matching rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe just convert it to string and match using `LIKE` (you need double because the path is closed):

```
select points::text  from things 
where (points::text || points::text) like '%(3,4),(5,6)%';
```

If you have a lot of things it`s worth to build index for the path, which will be used in the like query (you need [trgm extension](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/pgtrgm.html))

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS pg_trgm;
CREATE INDEX thing_text_paths ON things USING gin ( (points::text || points::text) gin_trgm_ops);
```

You can see it by running

```
SET enable_seqscan = OFF;
EXPLAIN select points::text  from things 
where (points::text || points::text) like '%(3,4),(5,6)%';
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/bd760/2/0

Comment: I will consider this, but I really would like to find a solution which leverages geometric operators. Otherwise, I might as well change this column's type to text.

Comment: @pdoherty926 Maybe still good to store it a path because it enforces the structure. What other operations will you do on the points?

Comment: Right, I do like the constraint and it provides a one-to-one mapping to the problem space (a list of points on a graph). As of now, I can't think of any other operations I'd be performing on the path.

Answer (score 1):

There is no native geometric operator in Postgres that would fulfill the assumptions. You can use arrays of points instead of paths, however it needs some preparations and an access as a superuser.

You need to create an operator class for the type `point` which allows to compare values of this type. The whole procedure is described in this post: [Creating custom “equality operator” for PostgreSQL type (point).](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34971757/1995738) Here you have a copy of my code I needed in one of my projects: [Postgres class point_ops.](http://rextester.com/NWQ93855)

The solution with arrays needs a simple function which you can use instead of an operator:

```
create or replace function is_subpath(point[], point[])
returns boolean language plpgsql as $$
begin
    for p in 1..cardinality($1) loop
        if $1[p] = $2[1] then
            for s in 2..cardinality($2) loop
                p:= p+ 1;
                if $1[p] <> $2[s] then
                    return false;
                end if;
                return true;
            end loop;
        end if;
    end loop;
    return false;
end $$;

drop table if exists things;
create table things(
    id int,
    points point[]
);
insert into things values
(1, '{"(3,4)","(1,2)","(5,6)","(7,8)"}'),
(2, '{"(1,2)","(3,4)","(5,6)","(7,8)"}');

select * 
from things 
where is_subpath(points, '{"(3,4)","(5,6)"}'::point[]);

 id |              points               
----+-----------------------------------
  2 | {"(1,2)","(3,4)","(5,6)","(7,8)"}
(1 row)
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll consider this approach. I'm surprised there's no native support for what I'm trying to accomplish, though. I imagine this must be a pretty common use case? Not that there is or should be a correlation, but in set theory, my parameter would qualify as a (potentially) _proper subset_ and many programming languages have methods for determining whether or not one set is a proper subset of another (e.g. `Ruby's Set#proper_subset?`).

Comment: Postgres has a rather modest set of geometric functions and operators. You may find more in [PostGIS](http://postgis.net/), but I do not know this extension well. See the edited answer with a function to find subpaths.

Comment: For bigger dataset this solution would be quite slow cos you get `O(s*p)` for each row check without any indexing.

Answer (score -1):

I would argue that you created the problem by your database design.  You should use two tables not just one.

If you followed Third Normal Form.  Your design would have a one to many relationship to the child table.

The child table would have four records in it.

If you followed the norms of how Sql works this would not be a problem.  When you put multiple data values in the same field Sql is not designed to handle that well and it limits you to kludge type solutions.

Comment: Can you give example how the search for subpath would look like than?