# PostgreSQL complains about inexistent comparison function for element in primary key

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2, postgresql-9.5

I have a table in a `PostgreSQL` database in which I want to store the following columns:

```
STATION   LOCATION    SERVICE    NORTH    EAST
text      point       text       real     real
```

Each tuple`(STATION, LOCATION, SERVICE)` is unique, so I decided to make it a composite type and make it the primary key.

However, when I try to insert a new entry in the database **I get the following error**:
`psycopg2.ProgrammingError: could not identify a comparison function for type point`

I guess it is complaining that you cannot order two points in a 2D plane, but I cannot see how that is relevant. I have managed to use composite types that made use of points as primary keys in a test example, so I cannot see how this is different.

I want to know:

- Why this is happening.
- How it can be fixed, preferrably without changing the table schema.

---

#### Debugging information:

```
testdb=> \d ERROR_KEY
Composite type "public.error_key"
  Column  | Type  | Modifiers 
----------+-------+-----------
 station  | text  | 
 location | point | 
 service  | text  | 

testdb=> \d testtable
    Table "public.testtable"
 Column |   Type    | Modifiers 
--------+-----------+-----------
 key    | error_key | not null
 north  | real      | 
 east   | real      | 
Indexes:
    "testtable_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (key)
```

For reference, this is the code I am using for the insertion:

```
from collections import namedtuple
import psycopg2

DB_NAME = 'testdb'
DB_USER = 'testuser'
DB_HOST = 'localhost'
DB_PASSWORD = '123456'

PVT_TABLE_NAME = 'testtable'

Coordinate = namedtuple('Coordinate', ['lat', 'lon'])

PVT_Error_Key = namedtuple('PVT_Error_Key',
                           ['station', 'location', 'service'])

PVT_Error_Entry = namedtuple(
    'PVT_Error_Entry', ['key', 'north', 'east'])


def _adapt_coordinate(coord):
    """
    Adapter from Python class to Postgre geometric point
    """
    lat = psycopg2.extensions.adapt(coord.lat)
    lon = psycopg2.extensions.adapt(coord.lon)
    return psycopg2.extensions.AsIs("'(%s, %s)'" % (lat, lon))


def _connect_to_db(db_name, db_user, db_host, db_password):
    """
    Connects to a database and returns a cursor object to handle the connection
    """
    connection_str = ('dbname=\'%s\' user=\'%s\' host=\'%s\' password=\'%s\''
                      % (db_name, db_user, db_host, db_password))
    return psycopg2.connect(connection_str).cursor()


def main():
    # Register the adapter for the location
    psycopg2.extensions.register_adapter(Coordinate, _adapt_coordinate)

    cursor = _connect_to_db(DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_HOST, DB_PASSWORD)

    # Create a dummy entry
    entry = PVT_Error_Entry(
        key=PVT_Error_Key(station='GKIR',
                          location=Coordinate(lat=12, lon=10),
                          service='E1'),
        north=1, east=2)

    # Insert the dummy entry in the database
    cursor.execute(
        'INSERT INTO %s '
        '(KEY, NORTH, EAST) '
        'VALUES((%%s, %%s, %%s), %%s, %%s)'
        % PVT_TABLE_NAME,
        (entry.key.station, entry.key.location, entry.key.service,
         entry.north, entry.east))

    # Retrieve and print all entries of the database
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM %s', (PVT_TABLE_NAME))
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    print(rows)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use a column of type `point` in a primary key, e.g.:

```
create table my_table(location point primary key);

ERROR:  data type point has no default operator class for access method "btree"
HINT:  You must specify an operator class for the index or define a default operator class for the data type.
```

The error message is clear enough, you need to create a complete btree operator class for the type.

The full procedure is described in this answer: [Creating custom “equality operator” for PostgreSQL type (point) for DISTINCT calls.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34971757/1995738)

---

Update. With the workaround you mentioned in your comment

```
create table my_table(
    x numeric,
    y numeric,
    primary key (x, y));

insert into my_table values
(1.1, 1.2);
```

you can always create a view, which can be queried just like a table:

```
create view my_view as
select point(x, y) as location
from my_table;

select *
from my_view;

 location  
-----------
 (1.1,1.2)
(1 row)
```

Comment: Thanks! I think I'll then convert the `point` into two `real`, defining all those operators is probably an overkill in my case :)